# Why a successful migration is showing (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored)?

Tags: 7, migrations

I have written a custom Migration tp import redirects (D7 -> D7).

Everything is working fine. Imports were successful, rollbacks are working fine etc.

However, I am getting `Processed XXXX (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) in XX seconds (XXXXX/min)` message after import.

Why is not showing the number of items created?

Is there a method in destination plugin or migration where I need to return this count or return TRUE/FALSE for each row processed or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Got answer!!

I missed the following code from the `abstract class MigrateDestination`:

```
/**
 * Maintain stats on the number of destination objects created or updated.
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $numCreated = 0;
public function getCreated() {
  return $this->numCreated;
}
protected $numUpdated = 0;
public function getUpdated() {
  return $this->numUpdated;
}
```

These variables need to be updated during the import process and need to be defined/updated in class that is extending the `MigrateDestination`.